# How to upload my custom WCF SOAP service to remote server?

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio, wcf

Everyone! I have have custom WCF SOAP service (chatbot with getAnswer method that takes a string) and my client (website). My **IService**:

```
namespace WcfServiceLab1
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetChatbotAnswerUsingDataContract(string question);
    }
}
```

**Service.svc**:

```
namespace WcfServiceLab1
{
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string GetChatbotAnswerUsingDataContract(string question)
        {
            Chatbot chatbot = new Chatbot();
            return chatbot.GetAnswer(question);
        }
    }
}
```

And my **ChatbotController**:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(string question)
        {
            try
            {
                ViewBag.ChatbotAnswer = obj.GetChatbotAnswerUsingDataContract(question.ToLower());
                ViewBag.YourQuestion = question;
                return View("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View("Index");
            }
        }
```

It's works on localhost, but when I upload my WCF service on free hosting using FTP and try to add Service References Visual Studio didn't find my service. It's here: http://chatbotservice.esy.es/WcfServiceLab1/
How to "install" wcf service on the remote server? What should I do?

Comment: That web server runs Apache so cannot host WCF services, currently the file contents are being served up raw, e.g. http://chatbotservice.esy.es/WcfServiceLab1/Web.config

Comment: Maybe I should try to use Microsoft Azure?